# prestashop customization impact price

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to build a function that reads the customization of a product in cart and adjust the price depends on the text in the customization.

I have tried overwrite getPrice() function and hit a road block where if there are 2 same products with different customization text, the code gets confused and don't know what do.

The customization text is an ID from another table which contains rules of how much should i add on the base price.

My question is: is there a way to make customization impact the price of a product in cart?

Comment: Hi, post please your code

Comment: only solution I found is add an extra product to the cart and give it the total of customizations, you could also impact the cart total with an override but that's not compatible with paypal payment module